# Keyboard controlled website

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am doing a project for visually impaired people. I want to build a website that can be totally controlled by keyboard. For eg: If he presses "Space" key div tag of some grouped links would be selected, then he could select the following links with Up and Down keyboard keys and enter the link when he presses Enter key. The website will be embedded with sound, for which I have completed working by now. I am newbie at web designing with Javascript, Ajax etc. So If anybody could help me with a little insight that would be awesome! 
Thanks
Yugesh

Comment: Try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.onkeypress

Comment: The space-bar _already_ does something (depending on where the keyboard focus is space-bar will scroll down or press buttons/checkboxes or - of course - type a space character), so I'm not sure I'd use that key for your function. Is this not re-inventing the wheel to some extent, given that there are browsing tools available for the visually impaired - presumably they already use such tools for general web-browsing, so then they'd have to learn your system for your website only. How does Ajax apply here?

Answer (score 1):

I guess a library that may be really useful to you is [keymaster](https://github.com/madrobby/keymaster).

It allows you to define key bindings, override the browser's default bindings, and supports scopes to enable / disable key bindings for various areas of your application.

Comment: good find! Golo, its very useful at least to me

Answer (score 0):

You just write the 'keypress' events and use key codes for special keys like 37-38-39-40 for left,top,right,bottom keys.